# How i can install playonlinux

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, uninstall, microsoft-office, official-repositories

when install POL the message

```
download failed:
E:htpp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
amd64 0.4.15ubuntu1.2 isnot (yet) available (403 forbidden [ ip:91.189.88.142 80])
```

Comment: Any question should always include the version of Ubuntu you are using. Please edit the question or add a flag. What version is it? It is possible the version affects the answer.

Comment: `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` plese add this to your question. Ist it really  `E:htpp:` then you have a typo in your sources.list

Answer (score 0):

Package available from the security/updates and focal/updates. Edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` as follows:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main restricted universe multiverse 
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libproxy1-plugin-gsettings
```